# Multiple instances of EJB 3.1 no-interface Singleton / Stateful session bean

Tags: java, interface, singleton, ejb, ejb-3.1

I want to access multiple instances `singletonA` and `singletonB` of a no-interface Singleton `MySingleton`. The instances are first defined in another Singleton `Configurator` class:

**MySingleton.java**

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class MySingleton {
    ...
}
```

**Configurator.java**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
public class Configurator {
    @EJB MySingleton singletonA;
    @EJB MySingleton singletonB;
}
```

The code above, appearently works.

Now, I need to inject these 2 instances of MySingleton in a Message-Driven Bean:

**MDB.class**

```
@Stateless
public class MDB implements MessageListener {
    @EJB (lookup="?")      MySingleton singletonA;
    @EJB (mappedName="??") MySingleton singletonB;
}
```

But at this point I am completely lost. I know that I could make things simpler by defining the 2 instances as 2 (empty) implementations of a unique interface. But I have some problems because the class contains some non static fields, so I can't define it as an Interface.

**EDIT**

Because of the nature of MDB, I can't pass the Singletons by reference.
Finally, I would like to avoid creating two identical implementations of MySingleton.

Thanks to the answers received I have been rethinking at the whole architecture and I must agree on the fact that having MySingleton defined as Stateful would be fine as well.

Comment: Based on edit: Singletons are generally very different from a Stateful, but they match Stateless beans better.  May be you can consider this fact when you redesign your application.  Stateless and Singleton both work on a request basis(in general) and do not maintain state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Configurator *MySingleton singletonA* and *MySingleton singletonB* are same. That is because whole point of @Singleton is to have only one instance, no matter how many times and where it is injected (in same JVM). Container creates instance before you inject it first time and after that same instance will be shared. So you can as well go and inject (rather only once) it again in *AnotherEJB*.

Even if we assume case without Singleton (Staless for example), using @EJB for injection does not produce new entries available for injection in somewhere else. So if you inject something via @EJB in class A, you cannot via injection pass reference to class B. To pass reference, method call is good way.

Comment: Agreed on the Singleton having only one instance. If I make it Stateful how can I get the 2 references in AnotherEJB?

Comment: You can have two (but different implementations) Singletons and just inject them wherever you need them. Generally you can pass reference to bean in method call, not via injection. Making bean Stateful or Stateless does not change too much in how to get reference to it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I haven't expressed well the real nature of AnotherEJB...I have just edited my question

Comment: Stateful bean does not sound like solution at all, especially because of MDB. Forget about Configurator, implement two different Singletons (maybe Singleton is good choice, hard to say because I do not know their purpose in your program) and inject them in your MDB.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you realize this is a contradiction. A `@Singleton` has only one instance, so you can't have two. Probably you need another kind of bean (a `@Stateful` ejb for example)